# Is there any get body tag method for WebElement class in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

I've been trying to get body of pages within HTML source. I've been trying it with `WebElement` Class. I can't access `invisibilityOfAllElements` method or let me say it throws error. I've written code like that:

```
WebElement element = waitBody.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(By.tagName("body")));
```

`waitbody` is object of `WebDriverWait` Class that I've defined. Eclipse highlights underline of `invisibilityOfAllElements`. Is there any idea to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invisibilityOfAllElements() expects a locator of type 'List of WebElement' but you are providing a 'by'.

Use invisibilityOfElementLocated instead.

Comment: I've changed and it throws error __Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to WebElement__ my new code as I shown below:

`WebElement element = waitBody.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));`

Comment: What do you want to do with that ? invisibilityOfElementLocated returns a boolean so it expects a boolean instead of a WebElement it should be something like that :
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 100);
        boolean element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));

Comment: Yes it's boolean but I have to define as WebElement. As I explained I want to fetch body tag of webpages. If I connect VPN, Selenium works slowly because of low connection speed. So I want to say to my code: Hey check the body tag of this page, you have 20 seconds for this. I've already defined `WebDriverWait waitBody = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);`

Comment: Ok, I am not sure I understood exactly what you mean but there exists 2 cases of wait, if you know your element will appear just use elementToBeClickable :
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.tagName("body")));
Otherwise use waitFor(2000); to force the wait

Comment: elementToBeClickable is also throws error too. I want to get text of body tag. How can I use waitFor? From which class? You can help me through https://meet.google.com/bsr-hyrr-zzr

Comment: String title = "";
waitFor(2000);

// you will wait 2s in order for everything on your page to be loaded

title = getDriver().findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
You can defined a method waitFor just like that :
    protected void waitFor(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: I did it but it didn't work too. I shouldn't make thread sleep. I need to use WebDriverWait and WebElement.  How can I show my all code to you? Maybe you can understand more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224117/discussion-between-sox-and-arthurmorgan).